# How to arc object with CGPathRef

Tags: ios, core-graphics, sprite-kit

In my iOS game, I am trying to move an object along a path (see below):

[image]

I want to move the triangle above around to the bottom of the box.

But I don't know how to use CGPathRefs very well. Here is what I am trying:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, 20, 0, 20, 0, M_PI/2, NO);
SKAction *moveTriangle = [SKAction followPath:path asOffset:YES orientToPath:YES duration:1.0];
[self.triangle runAction:moveTriangle];
```

And I keep getting odd results. Can anybody help me adjust my path to match the image above? Thanks!

Comment: tip: feed an SKShapeNode with the generated path to draw it on the screen. It can help tremendously to see what the results of any changes to the path creation are.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you could just set the anchor point of the triangle node to match the center point of the square and just rotate. Seems alot easier to do that, rather than make a path etc.

Comment: In terms of the path, what are the odd results that you are getting ? Would be helpful to understand what is happening. Odd results is vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using prototypical's idea**

```
     // will arc around this sprite for demo
    SKSpriteNode *boxOrange = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor orangeColor] size:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
    boxOrange.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:boxOrange];

    SKSpriteNode *heroSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor blueColor] size:CGSizeMake(70, 70)];
    CGFloat offeset = 150; // change as required, ie bring hero closer to rotn point
    heroSprite.position = CGPointMake(-offeset, heroSprite.position.y);
    SKSpriteNode *guideContainer = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor purpleColor] size:CGSizeMake(3, 3)];
    // for full effect - change guide container to clearColor
    // otherwise good for seeing where rotation point will occur
    [guideContainer addChild:heroSprite];

    [self addChild:guideContainer];
    guideContainer.position = boxOrange.position;

    [guideContainer runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:1.57 duration:3.0 shortestUnitArc:YES]];
    // just found shortestUnitArc action .. this will be handy for at times
```